# How to make a request to localhost via iOS device (using Xcode)?

Tags: ios, mysql, xcode, networking, server

I have a localhost website up at localhost:1336. When I run it on my simulator using Xcode, the app does not encounter any problem make a request to the localhost for data. But when I connect my iPhone via USB cable to the mac, and run the app on the iPhone device and makes the request, but then I get an error "Error- Could not connect to the server.".

I also confirmed that they are on the same Wi-Fi and using same IP. On Safari on my iPhone, I went to http://IPNumber:1336 and it was able to access the site via my iPhone. But some reason, through the app, it cannot connect to the server.

Any input or insight on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

the term 'localhost' means the same device, i think you mean a host on your local network? going localhost:1336 means your device is connecting to itself, its the same as going 127.0.0.1:1336. hence why it works on your simulator but not your phone, since your server and simulator are running on the same device

you have to use http://IPNumber:1336 in your app as well

Answer (score 1):

"Localhost" means the same device. If you are not running a HTTP service on your iPhone, you should not use "localhost".
Another point, you are using "http", if your iPhone is running iOS9+, you will need to check whether App Transport Security will be an issue, here is an article on how to do that: http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/